# DocuSign using TemplateID remote signing and Webhook notification for AutoResponded (non-existing signer email)

Tags: docusignapi

I'm not getting any webhook notifications for bad email addresses that respond back with unknown mail recipients. I do get a notification email for this but no webhook notification.

envelope code setup

```
    {
        var envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition()
        {
            EmailSubject = request.EmailSubject, 
            EventNotification = new EventNotification()
            {

                RequireAcknowledgment = "true",
                Url = config.Value.EnvelopeEventUrl,
                EnvelopeEvents = new List<EnvelopeEvent>
                {
                    //new EnvelopeEvent("Delivered"),
                    new EnvelopeEvent(EnvelopeEventStatusCode: "Voided"),
                    new EnvelopeEvent(EnvelopeEventStatusCode: "Declined"),
                    new EnvelopeEvent(EnvelopeEventStatusCode: "Completed", true.ToString()),
                },
                RecipientEvents = new List<RecipientEvent>
                {
                    new RecipientEvent(RecipientEventStatusCode:"AuthenticationFailed"),
                    new RecipientEvent(RecipientEventStatusCode:"AutoResponded"),
                    new RecipientEvent(RecipientEventStatusCode:"Delivered"),
                    new RecipientEvent(RecipientEventStatusCode:"Declined"),
                    new RecipientEvent(RecipientEventStatusCode:"Completed"),
                }
            },
            TemplateId = request.TemplateId,
            Status = "Sent",
            EmailSettings = new EmailSettings(ReplyEmailAddressOverride: "Reply@xxxxFinance.com.au", ReplyEmailNameOverride: "John Smith"),
    };
```

Sadly this DocuSign link is broken

[See Using Webhooks to Track Envelope Status for details](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/webhook-status)

Also I can't login to support using my DocuSign Demo account (Sandbox account), not sure why, so can't log a support ticket!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of - the link is not broken. Not sure what you meant by that.
Second, the issue here may be that sometimes remote servers do not respond back very quickly to let you know an email bounced.
You could try a different strategy where you look for the positive message (that the status of the recipient changed to indicate the email message was sent succsefully) and if you don't get that within say, 5 min - you assume it bounced (but that's on you, sometimes it is just delayed a lot).
See, you subscribed to five different recipient events. The one called "Delivered" is the positive (or opposite) of "AutoResponded" (which may also mean that the person had their Out-Of-Office message on). So, by checking if it was delivered, you can tell when the message got there safely, but not when it bounced for sure.

Comment: Good to hear that you guys at Docusign have fixed the link (back in April it returned an error).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using the "Delivered" as a positive, instead of the opposite "AutoResponded" negative which as you described is not guaranteed .